# How to receive and process JSON data from a URL in C # Web Service?

Tags: c#, json

How to receive and process JSON data from a URL in C# Web Service ?

I have a Web Service in C# and I must receive JSON data from a given URL.

Someone can give me an example of code that allows to receive JSON data and convert them into an object that allows me to treat the data for other operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at http://james.newtonking.com/json for parsing the json file (you can also download it from a nuget package).

So after you install it your code will look like this:

```
string url = "http://example.com/MethodThatReturnsJson";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string webServiceJsonString = client.DownloadString(url);

    YourObject yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(webServiceJsonString);
}
```